# Is it advisable to implement binary search tree with a reference to parent node?

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I am confused whether to use a reference to parent or not. It reduces algorithm complexity of delete operation significantly. But I have seen some compelling arguments against using it, like space requirement. So is this good to use parent pointer. Does production quality code use reference to parent or not?

Comment: depends on what sort of operations you are going to do frequently

Comment: If I need to do delete operation frequently, should I use parent pointer?

Comment: Production-quality code doesn't use homebrew binary tree solutions to begin with. And if it does, it's some very advanced use case.

Comment: Like Renjith said it all depends on how you will be using the treee.  If you want an answer you should provide more information on what the requirements in your case are.

Comment: *I have seen some compelling arguments against using it* What was the point of arguement?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik but it must be using some library. That library must be having some sort of standard code originated from good practices. So does that uses reference to parent?

Comment: A standard library solution will have many more tricks and finesses, resulting from many years of experience by many thousands of users. The issue of a parent reference is certain to get lost in the myriads of all other concerns being served.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: **It depends**.

Answering the following questions help:

1. What you want to do frequently?
2. What you want to do quickly?
3. How much memory do you have?

Parent pointer makes it easy to find Lowest Common Ancestor and also makes it easy to delete nodes.

What are you planning to use a BST for?

With more detail, we could help you more.

> Compelling arguments against it's use:

Just nit-picking:If it's compelling, why ask this question?

Anyway, if I were you I would include a reference to the parent node simply because it makes a ton of functionality easier to implement.

Again this ends up being a trade-off between time and memory.If you are willing to spend more on one, you can do better in the other factor.